# can two eigenvectors be same for a triangular matrix whose answer is have 3 eigenvalues which are same

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

so the matrix is `1  4  2
                0  1  6
                0  0  1`

the eigenvalues are 1,1,1
and i am getting **eigenvectors** :- [0,-1,2], and [1,0,0], [1,0,0]. 
can eigenvectors be same **?  if not can you please tell me where am i wrong ?**

---

How the vector [0,-1,2] was produced:

we get 2 equations , 
4x2 + 2x3 =0 ;
x3= 0 ;

4x2 = -2x3 ==> 2x2 = -x3
 now we cross multiply -1 and 2

we get
 x2/2 = x3/-1

then we were told  that x2 will be 2 and x3 will be -1

this is how i got the 2nd eigenvector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An eigenvector algorithm typically "tries" to produce a complete and linearly independent set of eigenvectors.  However, you are getting repeating eigenvectors because it is impossible to do this in your case since your matrix is not diagonalizable.

The vector $(1,0,0)$ is indeed an eigenvector of your matrix.  It is not clear to me why the vector $(0,-1,2)$ was produced.

---

Regarding your latest edit:

Your matrix was 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 4 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 1}.
$$
As you have correctly indicated, the way we find the eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$ (the only eigenvector in this case) is by solving the system given by $(A - I)x = 0$.  This produces the system of equations
$$
4x_2 + 2x_3 = 0\\
6x_3 = 0.
$$
You then correctly found the eigenvector $(1,0,0)$ by noting that the only solutions to this system are given by $x_2 = x_3 = 0$.  This presented a problem, however, since you expected 3 eigenvectors.

The correct solution at this point is to simply say that we can only produce 1 eigenvector, so the matrix is not diagonalizable.

The incorrect approach you attempted was to look for another solution to the system, with the thought that if $x$ solves only the first line then maybe that will be "good enough".  This is not the case: in order for $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to be an eigenvector, it needs to solve the **full** system of equations.

Comment: so what would be the 3rd eigenvetor ? because someon told me eigenvectors should be distinct

Comment: You get a complete set of distinct eigenvectors when your matrix is diagonalizable, which "usually" is the case.  However, because your matrix is not diagonalizable, there is no 3rd eigenvector.  In fact, there's no second eigenvector either.

Comment: yep , our teacher told us , eigenvector cant be zero , so the way he taught us  ,,,,,  is  :-   we get 2 equations  , 4x2 + 2x3 =0  ; and x3= 0 ;; 4x2 = -2x3 ==> 2x2 = -x3     now we cross multiply -1 and 2    we get x2/2 = x3/-1   and then he told us  ; x2= 2 and x3 = -1  this is how i got the 2nd eigenvector

Comment: @Pranay See my latest edit.

Comment: Omnomnomnom thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Let your matrix be $A$; then it's clear that the rank of $A-I$ is $2$, hence the nullity is $1$.

The eigenvector should be $(1,0,0)^T$.

Check that $(0,-1,2)^T$ is not an eigenvector.

Remark about your working to obtain $(0,1,-2)$ as an eigenvector.

From, $4x_2+2x_3=0$ and $x_3=0$, that would force $x_2=0$ as well. Notice that $(x_2,x_3)=(0,0)$ satisfies $2x_2=-x_3$ as well but $(0,-1,2)$ doesn't satisfy the equations.

Comment: i didnot understand , ... whats T  ? whats nullity ?

Comment: hmm... $T$ stands for transpose. ok, perhaps you haven't learn what is nullity. It is the number of independent number of vector that can be multiply to a matrix and still give you a zero vector. By studying $nullity(A-\lambda I)$, it tells you how many independent eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ are there.

Comment: how do we find nullity , and so you mean since nullity is 1 , there will be only 1 eigenvector for this matrix?

Comment: yes, we have the result that $rank(A)+nullity(A)=n$ where $n$ is the number of column. Rank is just the number of independent row. yes, we have exactly $1$ independent eigenvector.

Comment: but , then how are we supposed to find digonalization of this matrix , if there are no 2nd and 3rd eigenvectors ?

Comment: this matrix can't be diagonalized.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a case where eigenvectors are repeated and besides, for your matrix, you would only get the eigenvector $(1,0,0)^T$. I am not sure how you got $(0,-1,2)^T$. This also implies that your matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: e get 2 equations , 4x2 + 2x3 =0 ; and x3= 0 ;; 4x2 = -2x3 ==> 2x2 = -x3 now we cross multiply -1 and 2 we get x2/2 = x3/-1 and then he told us ; x2= 2 and x3 = -1 this is how i got the 2nd eigenvector  **thats how we were supposed to do**

Comment: I think @Omnomnomnom has left a brilliant explanation (as always :)) on where you have gone wrong. I could not have explained it any better.